# Error en android Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: android, excepciones

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que envía una imagen a un servidor pero al momento de enviarla me sale error. Debo enviarla por 3G/4G y no puedo hacerlo... es una ip pública

Aquí mi código

```
    URL url = new URL(webAddressToPost);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "test.jpg");
            entity.addPart("file", bab);

            entity.addPart("someOtherStringToSend", new StringBody("la cadena aquí"));

            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", entity.getContentLength() + "");
            conn.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(conn.getOutputStream());

            os.close();
            conn.connect();
```

y el error que me sale

```
    W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /IP (port 5000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.miguel.server11.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:141)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.miguel.server11.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:106)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    W/System.err:   ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el problema es tu conexión, es un [Timeout exception](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException):

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /IP (port 5000):
>   connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)Caused by:
>   libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: **ETIMEDOUT** (Connection timed
>   out)

Revisa si puedes realizar conexión on el servidor y debes revisar también si tienes permisos para realizar la petición `POST` hacia el servidor.

Comment: Por wifi si puedo conectarme y hacer el envío de imagen pero por 3G no